# failed installing libamd2.2.0, libumfpack5.4.0 and libatlas-sse2-dev

Tags: apt, package-management

I have a script I run on erach new machine I own, that installs somethings I need.

For some reason, on a dell Inspiron 3542 with Ubuntu 14.04, the following fails:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libamd2.2.0 libumfpack5.4.0  libatlas-sse2-dev
```

with the errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libatlas-sse2-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package libamd2.2.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libamd2.2.0'
E: Unable to locate package libumfpack5.4.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libumfpack5.4.0'
E: Package 'libatlas-sse2-dev' has no installation candidate
```

BTW,I did try `sudo apt-get update` first.

With other computers this always worked for me before. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two library packages are now `libamd2.3.1` and `libunfpack5.6.2`. As for the last package, `libatlas-sse2-dev` is a virtual package, which means it no longer exists as a standalone package, but might be provided by some other package (that I haven't found yet).

Comment: Thanks!!! How did u find out the new version numbers? is there a way to tell apt-get to just get the newest one?

Comment: Tab completion. After typing in `sudo apt-get install libamd`, if you hit tab, you should see what packages you can install.